# excel vba -soapclient30 "429 :ActiveX component can't create object" on 64 bit machines

Tags: excel, soap-client, vba

I have a macro that uses SoapClient30 to communicate with a web service
the macro snippet is

```
Dim client As SoapClient30
Set client New SoapClient30
```

this initialization works fine for 32 bit machines but when running on 64 bit machine It gives

```
"429 :ActiveX component can't create object"
```

error,I installed soap toolkit 3.0  on 64 bit machine also..
How can I use soap client on 64 bit machines? thanks

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: office 2000 it was...